# Excel - creating a graph based on single column results

Tags: microsoft-excel, macbook

I'm using a mac with office 2011

I have a gender conlumn like so:

```
gender
------
male
male
male
male 
female
male
male
male
male 
female
```

and would like to get a graph that will show 20% females, 80% males based on the values entered in the column cells.
if I had two columns one with the genders and one with the results then a simple
marked the columns --> clicked on graph --> selected pie will do the trick

I'm looking for a way to select a column--> the x axis will automatically get filled with the distinct values and the y will be a count result of the number they appear in it.

Is it possible?

Comment: Right click.. Select data

Comment: I did it marks all the cells as the range of y column and shows an empty chart

Comment: A pie chart won't do the math for you, it will just display your results.  You need to count the males and females and then plot the counts.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a VBA solution.

Answer (score 3):

Excel needs to be able to calculate the total number of each entry, so a Pivot Chart is an easy way to do this without adding a helper column.

To add a Pivot Chart;

1. Select your data, then go to the `Insert` tab and choose to insert a
   `Pivot-Chart`. This will create a new tab with pivot table and chart.
2. In the `Pivot Table Field List` on the right, drag `Gender` to `Row
   Labels` and again to `Values`. You should see table with the totals of each gender.
3. Now right click the chart and choose `Change Chart Type` and select
   `Pie`.

[image]

You can modify the chart as you need from there.